Master sheet which combines tab shopping lists but refers to which tab it came from?
I am trying to create a combined shopping list by collating all the data from various tabs within the sheet. But not sure how to pull tab name and potentially INDIRECT data from QUERY.
Combined List Screenshot

These shopping list tabs will all be laid out the same. See my Google Sheet below
Individual Shopping List

I have used the query function to pull this data, 'combined list'. I have made an additional column to track progress of the order. I tested to see if this got messed up when I added new data into the other shopping list tabs but seems ok.
Ideally, I would like to be able to pull through the tab name and potentially the cost code so I know where that data line came from and the date it was added. This will help when I filter by supplier and by tab name.
On every shopping list tab, the tab name is written in the H1 cell. Maybe INDIRECT would work for this? But I am not sure if it would work with the QUERY function?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19KCA6uyFlF97kLjkljmEzUDh5lUoYhVg-FyFSJXOOrU/edit?usp=sharing

Please remember that questions on this site should be specific and free of chitchat. If you would like to explore alternatives to what is the "main question", post a new question focused on a practical detailed programming problem, i.e., when writing code in Google Apps Script.

You should just create a new column in your I-MP and GD-MP sheets with the tab name so the QUERY function can bring those values over into the Combined List. Doing it any other way might be more trouble than it's worth.

When you want to combine multiple ranges for a QUERY function, creating an array is a straightforward process. Use curly brackets and the range references separated by a semicolon ;. On the Google Query (SQL-like) statement, instead of column references by column letter, you can use Col1 for the first array column, Col2 for the second array column, and so on.
Example:
=QUERY({Sheet1!A:Z; Sheet2!A:Z}, "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 is not null") 

For details on how to use arrays in Google Sheets please check the official help article: Using arrays in Google Sheets

Hi, I have already used QUERY code '=query({'I-MP'!A7:K;'GD-MP'!A7:K}, "select * where Col1 is not null")' . I am trying to get the lines on the combined list to reference which Tab they came from
